# Xcode 6.3/iOS 8.3 error from earlier versions

Tags: xcode, xcode6.3, ios8.3

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary?) -> Bool {
      UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
      UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
}
```

Not working when I updated from an older version of Xcode. The error is

> Objective C method 'application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:'
>   provided by method 'application(:didfinishLaunchingWithOptions:)'
>   conflicts with optional requirement method
>   'application(:didfinishLaunchingWithOptions:)' in protocol
>   'UIApplicationDelegate'

Comment: Sorry this was my first post, didn't know how to edit to show as code format...!

Comment: Could you define "not working" does the code seem to do nothing?

Comment: @NateLee It says... "Objective C method 'application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:' provided by method 'application(_:didfinishLaunchingWithOptions:)' conflicts with optional requirement method 'application(_:didfinishLaunchingWithOptions:)' in protocol 'UIApplicationDelegate'"

Answer (score 1):

You typed your method incorrectly (tip: autocomplete is a god)

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
     UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
     UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
     return true;
}
```

Comment: Now getting this:

"Parse.setApplicationId("****", clientKey: "****") {"

getting an error saying "expected declaration"...  didn't have this issue on an earlier version of Xcode

Comment: You still have to do that method to set up Parse if you have it in your project. The old project should have failed if you didn't set up these IDs in `didFinishLaunching`

Comment: Yeah that seems to have worked but this error has come up, could you please help me? It's like all the parameters have changed in one update :(

Comment: @VinoRodders Please do not "leech" one question on top of another. The question you asked was answered correctly. Accept that answer if it helped you. If you then have a new question, ask a new question.